# Stream UDP like TCP?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have a NetworkStream like you have in TCP, but in UDP?

I know UDP doesn´t allow checks and anything like that.

But i wonder if it´s possible to have it, so you can write in a Stream (instead of manually having to divide a Byte array into sizes that fits packages).

I am simply wondering this cause it would be nice to test and experiment with.

Comment: Can you live with the fact that packets may arrive out of order if you don't know where the boundaries are?

Comment: It´s for testing, so yes:)

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
writer.WriteLine("Stuff!");
writer.WriteLine("Things!");
...

var bytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
_udpClient.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, _host, _port);
```

On the reading side you can do this:

```
var bytes = _udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEP);
var packetString = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(bytes);
var reader = new StringReader(packetString);
reader.ReadLine();  // Stuff!
reader.ReadLine();  // Things!
```

Not exactly streaming (in-memory byte arrays can suck if you have lots of content) but this has worked for me with smallish packets.

Note that in my application it's perfectly fine if packets get lost or arrive out of order.  This must be so for your application as well or else UDP isn't for you.  The fact that you're thinking about your content as "streaming" suggests that you need to receive all the content that you send, in the same order.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that UPD is not reliable, so you could miss some data. 
You can handle UDP as stream, only sent by chunks.

Comment: I know it´s not reliable, but how can i handle it as a stream?

Comment: @Zerowalker UDP is lossy, if the receiver doesn't listen, you'll lose the package.. [read here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/udp-packet-loss)  You can't handle it like a stream. Either implement some sort of mechanism to check lost packages or just send full updates. (for example the positions of players in a game, you only want the last position and you don't want to queue it, Otherwise you could fall behind.)

Comment: So using it as a stream, means custom code to check for "missing" pakkets and request them again.